# VS2012 Signing Assembly Error - "Cannot find the certificate..."

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, sign

I'm trying to sign my app in VS2012 but I'm receiving "Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption" error.

What I do:

1. I received my certificate by Comodo CA Limited in Google Chrome.
2. Exported the certificate to a file with "Include all certificates" and "Export private key" options.
3. In VS2012, Signing tab I browse to the certificate file and fill in the password. The "Cannot find..." error appear.

I also tried all steps in this tutorial: [Visual Studio error 'Cannot find...](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1078)  in Comodo Knowledge Base, but no success.

The same key works fine when signing with the Comodo kSign tool and also when using signtool.exe

....

> The most common problem arises when using a .pfx file that contains
>   chaining information. You can remove chaining information from the key
>   file by running the Certificate Manager snap-in (Certmgr.msc),
>   importing the pfx file into the personal certificate store, and then
>   exporting it without including the certificate chain information.

Importing the certificate in MMC and exporting again doesn't help

...

I tried it on other machine, but the same problem. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730868%28vs.80%29.aspx#rsvssign_topic3

> The .pfx file cannot include certificate chaining information. (If the .pfx file does include this information, the following import error will occur: "Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.")

Just do not set "Include all certificates" while exporting the *.pfx file

Comment: Well, that was easy.